# Got an error that is "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: object is not a constructor(…)"

Tags: typescript, ionic2

When open the app on browser using "ionic serve" command, I get below error, could please help to check? Thanks!

Please refer to my codes in https://github.com/aaronchen2k/mobistore-client/tree/master/app

Comment: Please post a specific code fragment where the error occurs. The stacktrace in the browser console will contain the file name and the line number.

Comment: Can not find the cause, since I only get below messages:    

Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
undefined:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: object is not a constructor(…)
app.bundle.js:62129 http://localhost:8080/ms/api/v1/home/index
app.bundle.js:62136 Object {code: 1, data: Object}
app.bundle.js:51268 swiper initEvents attach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem come from angular2-es6, but your code can run with that error without any problem.
(see : https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-es6-starter/issues/1)
There are some fix in the issue too (dancing with dependencies to find the good one).